# How to set UIImageView.image to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uitoolbar

I want to set image from UIImageView.image to my bar button. The bar button works fine when i set the image giving it's name (eg. @"cameraImageButton.png"), however when i do myBarButton.image = UIImageView.image (and this UIImage exists, consist same @"cameraImageButton.png") the button doesn't show up.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelBarButton = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"Cancel" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(done)];
cancelBarButton.image = cancelImageView.image;
```

And here is the one that works (but i want to set image from cancelImageView):

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveBarButton = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"Save" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(takePhoto)];
saveBarButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cameraImageButton.png"]];

//init for flexItem and cancelBarButton

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cancelBarButton, flexItem, saveBarButton, nil];
[cameraToolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

Comment: That looks like it ought to work - are you definitely sure that cancelImageView has its image set at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImageView.image` is a property not an object. It is `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image` in [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and also in `UIBarButtonItem` Class. Only object or nil can be passed to set the property.

Comment: Can you explain this further? Surely cancelImageView.image returns a UIImage object?

Comment: Well, many years passed, but I need to clarify this. `UIImageView.image` is a property of `UIImageView` but obviously it is also an object.